# How to Mask and Unmask a panel

Tags: extjs5

I have a button 'Search'. When I am clicking it, it is doing some search and loading data in the grid.

I want to add Mask and Unmask functionality here. I am using extJS5

```
                {
                    xtype: 'button', 
                    text: 'Search',
                    handler : function () {
                        var searchPanel = Ext.getCmp('searchPanel'),
                            grid = Ext.getCmp('searchResultsGrid'),
                            searchCrit = searchPanel.gatherCriteria();
                        Ext.getBody().mask("Loading Data ..");
                        grid.executeSearch(searchCrit);
                        Ext.getBody().unmask();
                    }
                }
```

I have addedd `Ext.getBody().mask("Loading Data ..");` and `Ext.getBody().unmask();`. But it's not working properly.

Any idea, how to mask and unmask a panel in an event.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which proxy you use.
If you use memory proxy, then mask is not showing, because everything is executed at once, and browser not manage to make it visible. IMO the best way to make it visible is by using `defer`:

```
Ext.getBody().mask("Loading Data ..");
Ext.Function.defer(function() {
    grid.executeSearch(searchCrit);
    Ext.getBody().unmask();
}, 10);
```

That will give browser enough time to make mask visible.

If you use any other proxy, then grid loads data asynchronously, so you need to unmask it after `load` event is fired, no after `executeSearch` call:

```
Ext.getBody().mask("Loading Data ..");
grid.executeSearch(searchCrit);
grid.on('load', function() {
    Ext.getBody().unmask();
}, grid, { single: true });
```

BTW grid by default has masking enabled (`loadMask` configuration parameter from `Ext.grid.View`). You might have something missconfigured. Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/seur2aLx/9/